# How to solve .NET Framework compatibility error

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, .net-framework-version

I recently installed the latest version of .NET Framework. When attempted to create a new Delphi project, I faced some trouble:

Delphi can't find native units like `Vcl.Forms` and `Vcl.Dialogs`, making that I have to import it from its folders.

After I imported it, I'm still not able to build project having the following messages:

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado."

"[Fatal Error] Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado."

Has anyone here ever been through that and or have any idea about how to solve it?

Comment: Did you install .NET 3.5

Comment: Check your environmental variables (you can check in the IDE itself, using Tools->Options->Environment Options->Environmental Variables) to see if there's a `PLATFORM` variable defined. If so, delete it. (The IDE sets this variable when you define a target platform, so it's looking for specific values.) You may need to reinstall Delphi if the PATH is now missing information as well. You've clearly done something different when you installed the latest version; I've got .NET 3.5, 4.0, and 4.5 installed on my Win7 machine, and all installed versions of Delphi work fine.

Comment: I did install .NET 4.5.

Comment: @KenWhite I could not access Tools -> Options under the same kind of message. I was avoiding to reinstall, but...

Comment: You can check the PLATFORM from Computer->Properties in the OS too, with Advanced System Settings->Advanced->Environment Variables. If you can run the IDE to try and create a new project, you should be able to access that dialog.  If you can't, do a repair (or uninstall/reinstall) of the IDE, because you've severely broken something. (As I said, I have no idea what it might have been, because I have several versions of .NET and several versions of Delphi installed (including D2007, XE, XE4, and XE5) with no problems.)

Comment: I've seen this, but cannot remember the resolution. Sorry. I suspect that some judicious websearch would reveal the answer.

Comment: Is it possible you nuked some files in your .NET 2.0 installation?   Do you have the `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Borland.Delphi.Targets` files still?

Comment: 4.5 is buggy. Ensuee you have 4.5.1 patches

Comment: @WarrenP This folder does exist but I did not find Borland references.

Comment: But I think I know what caused this issue. I unistalled an update on Windows Update. I don't remember the number exactly but it looks like the number referenced in file name of .NET 4.5.1 Patch. Anyway, thanks @ArnaudBouchez. What should I do with the question?

Comment: Actually it did not solve the problem at all. I tried repair delphi and event unistall and reinstall. The problem persists. I downloaded patch 4.5.1 but nothing happened. Still on the same page.

Comment: Formating HD solved e.e